# Comparison and assignment between pointer and integer C

Tags: c, pointers

I've a theoretical question about these two statements:

Assuming `p` a pointer to an Integer and `a` an Integer:

a) `if(p==a){.....}` or `if(p>a)`..

b) `p=a`;

All of them are illegal and `b` is especially dangerous but how does standard C consider them?

Reading the standard, I haven't found if they are errors, undefined behaviors, unspecified behavior, constraint violation, if one of them is legal or other.

Looking in the countless similar question, I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C11 (n1570) §6.5.8 [Relational operators] / 2:

> #### Constraints
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have *real type*; or
> - both operands are *pointers* to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible object
>     types.

(real type means the integer types, enums, real floating point types and `char` (§6.2.5/17))

§6.5.9 [Equality operators]

> #### Constraints
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have *arithmetic type*;
> - both operands are *pointers* to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a *pointer* to an object type and the other is a *pointer* to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`; or
> - one operand is a *pointer* and the other is a *null* pointer constant.

§6.5.16.1 [Simple assignment] / 1:

> #### Constraints
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified *arithmetic type*, and the righ has *arithmetic type*;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a *structure* or union type compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified *pointer type*, and (considering
>     the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
>     *pointers* to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
>     to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified *pointer type*, and (considering
>     the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer
>     to an object type, and the other is a *pointer* to a qualified or unqualified version of
>     `void`, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to
>     by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified *pointer*, and the right is a *null*
>     pointer constant; or
>     the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified `_Bool`, and the right is a
>     *pointer*.

Basically, all 3 expressions **violated the constraints** set in the expression.

---

What does violating constraints mean? Errors? But nowhere says that violation of constraints shall cause the translation to fail. The C standard doesn't seem to be very clear, but the closest interpretation would be:

§4 [Conformance] / 2:

> If a “shall” or “shall not” requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

but this talks about *outside* of constraints; and §5.1.1.3 [Diagnostics] / 1:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
>    an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
>     contains a *violation of any syntax rule or constraint*, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be      produced in other circumstances.

so the compiler needs to at least produce a message (as we can see in gcc), but did not say what they should do after that.

The example after this paragraph mentions that

> #### EXAMPLE
>
> An implementation shall issue a diagnostic for the translation unit:
>
> ```
>    char i;
>    int i;
> ```
>
> because in those cases where wording in this International Standard describes the behavior for a construct as being both a constraint error and *resulting in undefined behavior*, the constraint error shall be diagnosed.

and §6.7 [Declarations] / 3 does not explicitly mention that violating the Constraint will cause undefined behavior.

Therefore, I deduce that your 3 expressions are all **undefined behaviors, accompanied with diagnostic messages**.

Answer (score 5):

All are illegal. To perform comparison, both sides most be convertible to a common type, for assignment, the right-hand side must be convertible to the type of the left-hand side, and:

> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of
>   6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

(**6.5.4**, 3; 6.5.16.1 describes some exceptions for the null pointer constant, `void` pointers and `_Bool` in the case of assignment.)

When you do add explicit casts to convert the pointers to integers, the program becomes valid again and you will get booleans from the comparisons. The results are implementation-dependent. Be sure to use `uintptr_t` when storing pointers in integers.

Answer (score 0):

Both a) and b) are constraint violations.  [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 6.5.8 , § 6.5.9, and § 6.5.16.1.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I'm actually answering your question, but here goes. Concerning a), you have a comparison, so what you're basically saying is "does the pointer have the memory address a?". In b) you're assigning to the pointer the value a, which means you are saying it will point to the memory address "a". Here go a few tips:

```
p=&a
```

Your pointer is now pointing to the memory address of integer a.

```
*p=a
```

The value to which your pointer is pointing takes the value of a.

```
p=a
```

Your pointer is now pointing to the memory value a.

Hope it helped!

Comment: The OP is asking what the C standard has to say about this, and the standard has no notion of a "memory address".