# Malloc / Free with enum gives segmentation fault - simple code

Tags: c, enums, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I tried to allocate some memory for a single enum variable but my code gives me segmentation fault. It prints out 2 and 3 as it should but at the end show seg fault too, why?

I'm using gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum direction
{
    up, down, left, right
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    enum direction d1;
    d1 = left;
    printf("%d\n", d1);

    enum direction *d2;
    d2 = malloc(sizeof(enum direction));
    d2 = right;
    printf("%d\n", d2);
    free(d2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try: *d2 = right; printf("%d\n", *d2);

Comment: Do you compile with any warnings enabled? Because the compiler should be flashing the warning-lights.

Answer (score 3):

`d2` is a pointer, not an enum. You cannot assign an enum value to it. It should be

```
*d2 = right;
```

This dereferences the pointer and you're putting `right` into the memory pointed to by the `d2`. The way you do it overwrites the pointer itself.

You should also check the return value of `malloc` before using it to make sure it's a valid pointer.

```
d2 = malloc(sizeof(enum direction));

if (d2 != NULL)
{
    *d2 = right;
    ...
    free(d2);
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: @BrianBrown Lol, happens to everyone. :)

Comment: Apparently he can assign an enum to `d2` because the program compiled and ran.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I meant to say it's not legal to assign the enum to the pointer. Depending on compiler settings, the problem may get hidden. I'm not terribly familiar with gcc.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's legal only in that it's legal to put any binary value in any memory location. It doesn't mean it's going to work. Putting `right` in the pointer is legal in a very broad sense of the word.

Comment: I think the assignment is illegal, UB, and the compiler is obliged to warn at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640943/comparison-and-assignment-between-pointer-and-integer-c

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
printf("%d\n", d2);
```

You pass a pointer to a `%d` format specifier which results in undefined behaviour.

And here

```
d2 = right;
```

you overwrite the variable holding the address of the dynamic memory allocated when you called `malloc`. Hence

```
free(d2);
```

attempts to free something that was not allocated with `malloc`. That results in undefined behaviour.

Presumably you meant

```
*d2 = right;
printf("%d\n", *d2);
```

I suggest you turn on all warnings and heed them. If you do so I am confident that your compiler can identify the problem before you even get as far as running the program.

Comment: Why didn't you make that last paragraph ***bold***? That's the askers problem, the rest is just the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
d2 = right;
```

is an ill-formed expression statement. `d2` is a pointer. `right` is an integer. It is illegal to assign integer values to pointers (unless the integer is a zero constant). It is an "error" in C language. It won't compile in a pedantic C compiler. Any compliant compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message for this assignment. GCC compiler does that too. Apparently, you simply ignored that diagnostic message. That means that the behavior of your program is not defined by C language. It is not a C program.

Another GCC diagnostic message you likely ignored is the one for this statement

```
printf("%d\n", d2);
```

It should've told you that `printf`-ing pointers through `%d` format specifier is illegal.

Don't ignore diagnostic messages issued by the compiler. In many cases that will help you to answer questions like "why does my program segfaults" by yourself.

P.S. As a curious side note: `d2 = up;` would actually be a perfectly valid assignment. The program would not crash, it would simply leak memory.